# How can I RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak for TCriticalSection

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-2007

This maybe simple. How can I register a memleak for TCriticalSection with Indy9 in D2007 ?
I found [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak) but no example.

EDIT:
Thanks Remy for the reply, but it didn't work for me. In Indy9 directory I change IdComponent.pas from

```
initialization
  GStackCriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
finalization
  // Dont Free. If shutdown is from another Init section, it can cause GPF when stack
  // tries to access it. App will kill it off anyways, so just let it leak
  // FreeAndNil(GStackCriticalSection);
```

to

```
initialization
  GStackCriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
  RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(GStackCriticalSection);
finalization
  // Dont Free. If shutdown is from another Init section, it can cause GPF when stack
  // tries to access it. App will kill it off anyways, so just let it leak
  // FreeAndNil(GStackCriticalSection);
```

The same leak as before. I could set a breakpoint on TCriticalSection.Create so I know the code is actually executed. But the strange thing is that if I set a breakpoint on FastMM's RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak it is never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the `TCriticalSection` object pointer to `RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak()` like any other parameter, eg:

```
var
  CS: TCriticalSection;
...
RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(CS);
```

Just make sure the `TCriticalSection` has been instantiated befor you register it.

Or, you could upgrade to Indy 10, which already registers its intentional leaks for you (or you can define `FREE_ON_FINAL` in IdCompilerDefines.inc to disable the leaks - read the comments at the bottom of IdStack.pas and IdThread.pas before doing so).